# animating in reverse direction on class removal and addition in vue

Tags: css, vue.js

So I making a help button which pop up a help-dialogue box on a button click with some animations

This is my template.

```
<template>
  <div class="help">
    <button v-if="theme" class="help-icon" @click="helpOpen">?</button>
    <section class="help-dialogue-box"
      :class="{ 'help-open': isHelpOpen, 'help-close': isHelpOpen === false }">
      
    </section>
  </div>
</template>
```

this is my css part

```
.help-dialogue-box{
  position: absolute;
  transform: translateX(50%) scale(0, 0);
  top: 50%;
  right: 50%;
  background-color: honeydew;
  width: 75vw;
  height: 90vh;
  border-radius: 500px;
  pointer-events: none;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.help-open{
  animation-name: expand;
  animation-duration: 2s;
  animation-direction: normal;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  pointer-events: all;
}

.help-close{
  animation-name: expand;
  animation-duration: 2s;
  animation-direction: reverse;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes expand{
  0%{
    transform: translateX(50%) scale(0, 0);
    border-radius: 500px;
  }

  50%{
    transform: translateX(50%) scale(0.6, 0.6);
  }

  100%{
    transform: translateX(50%) scale(1, 1);
    border-radius: 5px;
  }
}
```

and if needed the script part.

```
  data(){
    return {
      isHelpOpen: null
    }
  }

  methods: {
    helpOpen(){
      this.isHelpOpen = !this.isHelpOpen;
    }
  }
```

so when the help-open class is added it animates perfectly but when the help-close class gets added and help-open gets removed there is no animation in reverse direction, actually no animation at all (the section disappear immediately). I've tried adding and removing the classes manually by removing and adding the classes one by one but it didn't work.

Am I doing anything wrong here?

I basically want the element to animate in reverse direction when the help-open class is removed.

Comment: Have you tried using the in-build `transition` provided by vue?
https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/transitions.html#Transitioning-Single-Elements-Components

Comment: @YashMaheshwari yes it works thank you so much......i didn't knew that transition thing exisited......vue has some cool features!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vue provides an in-build [transition](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/transitions.html#Transition-Modes) functionality to easily implement the transitions.
There are also some in-built [mode](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/transitions.html#Transition-Modes) which you can use with the transitions. Even if you want some custom transitions then you can use the [custom transition classes](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/transitions.html#Custom-Transition-Classes).